# Angular switchMap sending undefined data to service

Tags: angular, switchmap

I have two observable called: callbacks and system.

I want to merge some data, so in my callback I have the property "systemId"  and in my system I have the the property "name"

**CallbackObservable:**

```
this.callbacksService.toGetAllCallbacks().subscribe(callbacks => console.log(callbacks));
```

**Result : One Array of object**

```
[{...}]
0:
id: "555"
name: "teste 2 "
systemId: "123"
```

**SystemObservable:**

```
this.sistemaService.toGetSistemaById('123').subscribe(nome => console.log(nome));
```

**Result: One Object**

```
  {
    id: '123',
    name: 'teste',
   }
```

I want the result to be an array of callbacks with the id and name of the system like this:

```
{
id: "555"
name: "teste 2"
systemId: "123"
systemName: "teste"
}
```

So I tried using switchMap operator:

```
 this.callbacksService.toGetAllCallbacks().pipe(
      switchMap((element) => {
        return this.sistemaService.toGetSistemaById(element.systemId);
      })
    ).subscribe(data => {
      this.dado = data
      console.log(this.dado);
    });
```

It didn't work because on my second call to the service, it's sending 'undefined' and I don't know why.

[image]

Am I using switchmap in a wrong way?

Comment: the first observable is emitting an array as you mentioned, but you are trying to access systemId which is undefined.

Comment: You should do `switchMap(element => this.sistemaService.toGetSistemaById(element))`

Comment: Which is the best way to map inside the element property and then call the service?

Answer (score 0):

The first call `this.callbacksService.toGetAllCallbacks()` returns an array, so when you try to pass `element.systemId` this is undefined. So if i understood correctly you want to merge each array of the first call with the corresponding response from the second call. I dont know if this solution is the best, but it works:

```
this.callbacksService
  .toGetAllCallbacks()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap((data) => data),
    concatMap((element) => {
      return this.sistemaService.toGetSistemaById(element.systemId)
       .pipe(
        switchMap((elem) => {
          element.systemName = elem.name;
          return of(element);
        })
      );
    }),
    toArray()
  )
  .subscribe((data) => {
    this.dado = data;
    console.log(this.dado);
  });
```

Comment: thank you for you answer, I tried but got the same error

Comment: Yes,  you are right, i made an edit, check now